# AltBeacon: Start a beacon on android

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

Is it possible to create an AltBeacon (so start advertising) on Android with the official Android AltBeacon library?
https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library

Much like we can create an AltBeacon using the iOS libray and start advertising (https://github.com/CharruaLab/AltBeacon) can advertising be achieved on Android 4.3+ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Android Beacon Library to transmit, but it requires Android L and is not possible with Android 4.3.  See the sample transmitter app here:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/altbeacon-transmitter-android

This sample app is based on a branch of the library that targets the new Android L operating system and provides a [BeaconTransmitter](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/android-l/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconTransmitter.java) class.  Once Android L is released, this branch will be merged into the official release of the library.

The reason transmitting requires Android L is because Android 4.3 does not support BLE Peripheral mode needed to transmit as a beacon.

It is also important to note that the iOS AltBeacon project from CharruaLabs Lab mentioned above is completely independent and uses a different incompatible transmission format.

Comment: That's a bummer, but understandable, thank you. Do you guys have an iOS lib that can create AltBeacons that are scannable via your Android AltBeacon library?

Comment: No, unfortunately both the iOS and OSX CoreBluetooth APIs block transmitting any beacon signal other than for iBeacon.  Beacon transmissions typically rely upon the "manufacturer data" section of BLE advertisement packets, and Apple APIs block putting any data in these fields other than for iBeacon transmissions purposes.  Software AltBeacon transmitters are therefore limited to Linux and Android L.